# AWS Lightsail to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-lightsail

I'm currently working on a project where we have a number of AWS Lightsail instances. We are looking at moving away from Lightsail towards using AWS ECS.

From experience it looks like we may need to first export the Lightsail Instances to EC2 first?

If anyone has any links/guides or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting your VMs from Lightsail to EC2 isn't going to be of much (if any) help. ECS runs containers. You are going to need to containerize your applications. How you would do that would depend entirely on what exactly your applications are.